# Is it possible to have conditional dependencies in a Package.swift target depending on the platform?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift-package-manager

I am trying to build a Swift package, where one of the targets must depend on a different version of a library depending on whether it is being built for iOS or MacOS.

For iOS, the dependency is packaged as an `.xcframework`, whereas for MacOS it is packaged as a system library.

So my dependencies package looks like this:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.6
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "LibFoo",
    products: [
        .library(name: "LibFooFramework", targets: ["LibFooFramework"]),
        .library(name: "ClibFoo", targets: ["ClibFoo"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "LibFooFramework",
            path: "path/to/LibFooFramework.xcframework"
        ),
        .systemLibrary(
            name: "ClibFoo",
            pkgConfig: "libFoo"
        )
    ]
)
```

So then in my client package, I want to use one of these dependencies depending on the target platform.

I have tried this:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.6
import PackageDescription

#if os(iOS)

let conditionalTarget: Target = .target(
    name: "MyLib", 
    dependencies: [
        .product(name: "LibFooFramework", package: "LibFooFramework")
    ]
)

#else

let CVulkanUtilsTarget: Target = .target(
    name: "MyLib", 
    dependencies: [
        .product(name: "ClibFoo", package: "LibFoo")
    ]
)

#endif

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLib",
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLib", targets: ["MyLib"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/spencerkohan/LibFoo", branch:"master")
    ],
    targets: [
        .library(
            name: "LibFooFramework",
            path: "path/to/LibFooFramework.xcframework"
        ),
    ]
)
```

But it seems that the package manager *always* takes the else branch, even if the package is being built for iOS.  I guess this is because the os target of the `Package.swift` will always be the build environment and not the target.

But is there any way to achieve this type of conditional dependency?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md